# em c qual o erro deste código

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char marca[100]; //vetor de char, representa um string
    int ano_de_Fabricacao;
    char cor[100];
    preco float; //considerar descontos inteiro em % (20%, 5%)
}CARRO;

CARRO * criarCarro(){
    CARRO *ptr_carro = (CARRO *) malloc(sizeof(CARRO));

    if(ptr_carro == NULL){
        printf("Memória insuficiente! Não alocar espaço para produto.");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (ptr_carro);
}

void lerDados(CARRO * novoCarro){
    printf("Digite a MARCA do produto: \n");
    gets(novoCarro->marca);

    printf("Digite o ANO_DE_FABRICACAO do produto: \n");
    scanf("%d",&novoCarro->ano_de_Fabricacao);

    printf("Digite o COR do produto: \n");
    scanf("%f",&novoCarro->cor);

    printf("Digite o PRECO do produto: \n");
    scanf("%d",&novoCarro->preco);
}

void imprimirDados(CARRO * novoCarro, float valorVenda){
    printf("\n**** VENDA DE PRODUTO ****\n");
    printf("Marca: %s\n", novoCarro->marca);
    printf("Ano_de_Fabricação: %i\n", novoCarro->ano_de_Fabricacao);
    printf("Cor: %i%%\n", novoCarro->cor);
    printf("Preco: %.2f\n", novoCarro->preco);
    printf("Valor de venda: %.2f\n",valorVenda);

}

float calcularValorVenda(CARRO * novoCarro){
    return (novoCarro->preco - (novoCarro->preco * novoCarro->desconto/100));
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    CARRO *ptr_carro = criarCarro();

    //leitura dos dados
    lerDados(ptr_carro);

    float valorVenda = calcularValorVenda(ptr_carro);

    //impressão dos dados da struct PRODUTO na tela
    imprimirDados(ptr_carro, valorVenda);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `preco float` está invertido. Use `float  preco;` Poste um programa completo, compilável.

Comment: Você declarou `char cor[100]; preco float;` mas não faz a leitura compatível com esta definição ` printf("Digite o COR do produto: \n"); scanf("%f",&novoCarro->cor); printf("Digite o PRECO do produto: \n"); scanf("%d",&novoCarro->preco);`

Answer (score 1):

andrei,

Seu programa tem problemas menores nas declarações, coisas que seu compilador já deve ter mostrado, como

- `preco float;` ao invés de `float preco;` na declaração
- `scanf()` para ler cor, um `char[100]`, usando especificador `%f`
- `scanf()` para ler `preco`, um `float`, usando `%d`
- `printf()` para mostrar `cor`, `char[100]`, usando `%i%%`
- uso do campo `desconto` que não aparece em `CARRO`

Talvez pudesse ter resolvido isso mais facilmente apenas acompanhando as mensagens do compilador. Mas não é só isso:

#### sobre `scanf()`

`scanf()` retorna um valor, e você deve muito testar. O valor é o total de itens lidos e vai te dizer se `scanf()` conseguiu ler algo. Se você não tratar esse retorno vai assumir um risco deixando o programa seguir cegamente

#### gets()

Não use `gets()`. Use `fgets()` porque ela limita o tamanho do que pode ler. Se o usuário digitar além da capacidade do campo vai cancelar seu programa

#### free()

você aloca memória para um único CARRO, mas não libera em lugar nenhum. Mesmo em casos simples assim deve confirmar que liberou cada byte que alocou. Seus próximos programas devem ser mais sofisticados e vão se beneficiar desse hábito. Ou vai ser penalizado pela falta dele.

#### Nova linha ao ler campo

Não faça isso. Deixe a leitura logo depois do prompt da questão . É assim em todo lugar, por uma razão: é melhor manter o contexto

#### iteração

Quase certamente não pretendia ler um único `CARRO` então sua estrutura não vai funcionar. Precisa de uma vetor de carros, ou uma lista ligada de carros, algo que permita guardar as informações na memória. E não fez isso.

#### protótipos

`main()` deve ser a primeira função de seu programa, sempre. Em geral em um arquivo separado. A razão é simples, já que a execução sempre começa em `main()`. Use protótipos, junto com as declarações de estruturas, se possível em um arquivo header --- .h --- separado. Há uma razão para isso ser feito desde os '70.

Veja o exemplo abaixo

#### uma versão do seu código que ao menos roda

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char marca[100]; //vetor de char, representa um string
    int ano_de_Fabricacao;
    char cor[100];
    float preco; //considerar descontos inteiro em % (20%, 5%)
}CARRO;

CARRO* criarCarro() {
    CARRO* ptr_carro = (CARRO*)malloc(sizeof(CARRO));

    if (ptr_carro == NULL) {
        printf("Memória insuficiente! Não alocar espaço para produto.");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (ptr_carro);
}

void lerDados(CARRO* novoCarro) {
    printf("Digite a MARCA do produto: \n");
    gets(novoCarro->marca);

    printf("Digite o ANO_DE_FABRICACAO do produto: \n");
    scanf("%d", &novoCarro->ano_de_Fabricacao);

    printf("Digite o COR do produto: \n");
    scanf("%f", &novoCarro->cor);

    printf("Digite o PRECO do produto: \n");
    scanf("%d", &novoCarro->preco);
}

void imprimirDados(CARRO* novoCarro, float valorVenda) {
    printf("\n**** VENDA DE PRODUTO ****\n");
    printf("Marca: %s\n", novoCarro->marca);
    printf("Ano_de_Fabricação: %i\n", novoCarro->ano_de_Fabricacao);
    printf("Cor: %i%%\n", novoCarro->cor);
    printf("Preco: %.2f\n", novoCarro->preco);
    printf("Valor de venda: %.2f\n", valorVenda);

}

float calcularValorVenda(CARRO* novoCarro) {
    return (novoCarro->preco - (novoCarro->preco * novoCarro->desconto / 100));
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    CARRO* ptr_carro = criarCarro();

    //leitura dos dados
    lerDados(ptr_carro);

    float valorVenda = calcularValorVenda(ptr_carro);

    //impressão dos dados da struct PRODUTO na tela
    imprimirDados(ptr_carro, valorVenda);

    return 0;
}
```

**Que mostra**

```
Digite a MARCA do produto:
Aston Martin DB5
Digite o ANO_DE_FABRICACAO do produto:
1964
Digite a COR do produto:
Prata
Digite o PRECO do produto:
18000000

**** VENDA DE PRODUTO ****
Marca: Aston Martin DB5

Ano_de_Fabricação: 1964
Cor: Prata
Preco: 18000000,00
Valor de venda: 18000000,00
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```